# Will any route (built without a destination ticket) be counted as points?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, scoring

Will any routes, built without a destination ticket, be counted as points?

In other words, can you get **any** points if your built any segments **without** the appropriate destination ticket?
Can you build them anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

You score points for EVERY route you claim, based on its length (length 1 is 1 point; length 2 is 2, 3 is 4, 4 is 7, etc), at the time that you claim it. Destination cards are awarded (or penalized) at the end of the game.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in a few ways:

1. Each segment gets a score immediately when you build it, the longer the segment, the greater the points. This is completely independent of routes.
2. Longest route is another award during the end game, and this doesn't need to follow any of your destination routes (it usually includes at least part of some destination routes but is longer)

Destinations are probably the best way to earn points, since you get the points for each segment either way, and a player is not likely to win if they don't finish any destination routes, since they are a penalty if left unfinished, but they are far from the only way to score in Ticket to Ride.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can claim any route (as long as it's available) and you will score the appropriate number of points.

[Ticket to Ride Rules](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/7201-T2R-Rules-EN-2019.pdf)

> OBJECT OF THE GAME
>   ...Points can be scored by:
>     • **Claiming a Route between two adjacent cities on the map;**
>     • *Successfully completing a Continuous Path of routes between two cities listed on your Destination Ticket(s);*
>     • **Completing the Longest Continuous Path of routes.**
>
> *Points are lost if you do not successfully complete the route given on the Destination Ticket(s) you kept.*

---

> CLAIMING ROUTES
>   ...**A player may claim any open route on the board. He is never required to connect to any of his previously played routes.**

---

> CLAIM A ROUTE
>   ...He then records his score by moving his Scoring Marker the appropriate number of spaces (see Route Scoring Table) along the Scoring Track on the board.